# Incomplete string escaping or encoding

Tags: javascript

i ran a Code Scanning in Github in my repo , and this line in my JS file

```
t.location.href.split("#")[0].replace(/<[^>]*>/g,"").replace(/([\('\)])/g,"\\$1").replace(/ /g,"%20")
```

keeps giving the Alert :

```
Incomplete string escaping or encoding
```

Please help me fix it i've stuck here for the whole day .

Comment: You need to add a string before replace, for example if you were trying to replace characters in a string named str you would do str.replace()

Comment: Seems to be a [security warning](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/javascript/js-incomplete-sanitization/#incomplete-string-escaping-or-encoding) when sanitizing a string. Is it just the 2nd replace giving the warning?